# US Residential Database

Tags: data-request, geospatial, usa, geocoding, address

I am looking for a database that has addresses or coordinates of residential properties across the US. Data is to be used to identify areas feasible for energy developments.

I have tried OSM and the housing data is very high level.

Simply put I am looking for a list of residential property coordinates or addresses that could be geo-coded. Do not need any other information attributed to the points.

Comment: But what's wrong with OpenStreetMap data? Example query: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Gc1

Comment: Using GeoFabrik a lot of the data was missing. I have been unable to query the data using Overpass or other websites for any substantial area to run my assessment.